# How to handle Nested Category URL with pagination

Tags: codeigniter

I want to create a website in CodeIgniter using nested category URLs. Single category URLs are handled, but when a second level category shows in the URL, there is a problem.

Example:

```
www.example.com/classified/education/   
www.example.com/classified/education/12
```

this is OK.

But, `www.example.com/classified/education/admission` is a problem, because
pagination parameter generates a problem in the routes rule:
`www.example.com/classified/education/admission/12`

Because in first URL, second parameter is pagination number but in last URL parameter is category URL.

How to handle these conditions?

Answer (score 0):

try using this to get the parameter value. without your code, its hard to tell

```
$this->uri->segment(4)
```